# Living in a world with no mechanical friction

Tags: environment, alternate-worlds

What effects would produce living in a world with no mechanical friction, with all surfaces slick and clean?

Comment: Does this question imply that planets have already formed and life already exists? You might want to clarify your question a bit and possible narrow down the scope a little. Interesting premise though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the implications for society if perpetual motion was possible?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/what-are-the-implications-for-society-if-perpetual-motion-was-possible)

Comment: Do you mean how would people develop such a world? How would people look living in such a world? If you really mean an entire universe with no mechanical friction then life as we know it is essentially impossible.

Comment: No friction, oh boy! This used to be my favorite answer in a game we used to play: "If you could change one thing and it had to kill everyone what would you change?". Everyone gets to roll their own apocalypse. No friction at the very least means rain that falls like bullets, among other Fun Stuff.